# How to split CSVs from one column to rows in a new table in MSSQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, split, normalization

Imagine the following (very bad) table design in MSSQL2008R2:

```
Table "Posts":
| Id (PK, int) | DatasourceId (PK, int) | QuotedPostIds (nvarchar(255)) | [...] 
|     1        |        1               |                               | [...] 
|     2        |        1               |           1                   | [...] 
|     2        |        2               |           1                   | [...] 
[...]
|   102322     |        2               |     123;45345;4356;76757      | [...]
```

So, the column QuotedPostIds contains a semicolon-separated list of self-referencing PostIds (Kids, don't do that at home!). Since this design is ugly as a hell, I'd like to extract the values from the QuotedPostIds table to a new n:m relationship table like this:

```
Desired new table "QuotedPosts":
| QuotingPostId (int) | QuotedPostId (int) | DatasourceId (int) |
|        2            |        1           |         1          |
|        2            |        1           |         2          |
[...]
|      102322         |       123          |         2          |
|      102322         |      45345         |         2          |
|      102322         |       4356         |         2          |
|      102322         |      76757         |         2          |
```

The primary key for this table could either be a combination of QuotingPostId, QuotedPostId and DatasourceID or an additional artificial key generated by the database.

It is worth noticing that the current Posts table contains about 6,300,000 rows but only about 285,000 of those have a value set in the QuotedPostIds column. Therefore, it might be a good idea to pre-filter those rows. In any case, I'd like to perform the normalization using internal MSSQL functionality only, if possible.

I already read other posts regarding this topic which mostly dealt with split functions but neither could I find out how exactly to create the new table and also copying the appropriate value from the Datasource column, nor how to filter the rows to touch accordingly.

Thank you!

**€dit:** I thought it through and finally solved the problem using an external C# program instead of internal MSSQL functionality. Since it seems that it could have been done using Mikael Eriksson's suggestion, I will mark his post as an answer.

Comment: Can you show some code what you have done / where you have problems? Whats your problem with split? You won't get a full featured solution coded here.

Comment: I basically have a table funtion that can extract the semicolon-separated values from a given data row. What I don't know is how to apply that to every row in my table and how to add the result to a new table.

Comment: Because only constants and @local_variables can be passed to table-valued functions, you have to declare a cursor and step to all of your rows when you want to use a table function.

Comment: @Jan - Cursor is not needed for this. You can use `cross apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments you say you have a string split function that you you don't know how to use with a table.

The answer is to use `cross apply` something like this.

```
select P.Id,
       S.Value
from Posts as P
  cross apply dbo.Split(';', P.QuotedPostIds) as S
```

Comment: are you sure that works? I have read on books online that you can pass only constants and variables to a table valued function.

Comment: @Jan: That's the difference that APPLY brings. You can see similar examples in [this BoL article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx).